# Google Container Engine: Accessing Cloud Storage

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't get the Application Default Credentials working in Google Container Engine. The docs say that they're intended for App Engine and Compute Engine, but I've been told that they should transparently pass through to a container running on Container Engine.

Here's the code that's failing:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

The error it's failing with: `AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "memcache"`

Is it correct to expect Application Default Credentials to work with Container Engine? If not, can anyone recommend the proper way to connect to cloud storage from a container running on Container Engine?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** After running `gcloud beta auth application-default activate-service-account --key-file <my_key>.json` the `credentials` object in the above Python example is populated with data. However I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What runtime are you using?

Comment: @mgilson please let me know if this is what you're asking for:  `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

Comment: IIRC, container engine supports different python runtimes and not all of them support `memcache`.  (FWIW, this is outside of my experience, so I could be wrong -- I'm just pulling this up from the recesses of my mind where I seem to have cached some of this information for one reason or another ...)

Comment: @mgilson I used the official [Google container](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) for working with their cloud SDK. The `gcloud` commands do work out of the box from a terminal, but for some reason I can't get Python to authenticate correctly.

Comment: @mgilson thanks very much for the help. I found an alternate method of accessing cloud storage and posted it below.

Comment: Awesome.  My 2c probably doesn't mean too much, but if I were you, I'd edit the question to make it more clear what you're trying to accomplish rather than how you were trying to accomplish it (e.g. change the title to something like "Container Engine:  How to access Cloud Storage?".  Then, reference your attempt and the specific error message.  That way, it's more likely to be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @mgilson edited. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to access cloud storage on Container Engine appears to be the [gcloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/) library.

It won't work with zero configuration if the App Engine SDK is installed on the container (gcloud finds it and assumes it's running on App Engine). So I stopped using the official [Google container](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/).

On a [python container](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) just add **gcloud** to your **requirements.txt** (or run `pip install gcloud`). As long as the container lives on a Google Compute Engine instance you can access any bucket in the same project.

Example:

```
from gcloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('<bucket_name>')
blob = bucket.blob('test_file.txt')
blob.upload_from_string('test content')
```

The gcloud library also exists for [Java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.3/index.html), [Node](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/), and [Ruby](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-ruby).

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  I've edited the code to add the import statement as well -- Just to be explicit.