# How to properly access Google Cloud Storage from their Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking for the proper way to access storage from a container, all running in google's cloud.

I have the following test `script.py`:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my_test_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('test_file.txt')
blob.upload_from_string('test content')
```

and a Docker image that simply runs it (python 3.7).

The bucket is private and thus needs authentication, and that is where my problem lies.

Other users [say that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926671/google-container-engine-accessing-cloud-storage/37932083) this should happen transparently, as long as running in the correct project.
However, this did not work for me (since that question was answered, the python library has been deprecated in favor of `google-cloud-storage`, and Container Engine changed its name to Kubernetes Engine).

I managed to get it working by creating a service account and setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the json credential, but this requires putting private credentials inside the (possibly public) Docker image.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The proper way is to implement Kubernetes RBAC and Google Cloud IAM on your cluster. Then your pods can use the service account assigned (made available to) the pod(s). Start with this document: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control

Comment: Thanks :) First impression is it's not as simple as I would've hoped. I'll give it a try and report back with a solution if I manage.